# Which Java is Eclipse using?

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers' for Linux from eclipse.org. I am able to write, compile and run Java programs. But I don't understand what JDK / JRE is being used.

If I start a new 'Java Project' I can choose which JRE to use, but if I choose for instance 'JavaSE-1.6' I still don't know what that is? Oracle? IBM? And I don't know where that JRE is in my file system.

Let's say I want to use that same JRE to execute my Java program from command line, how do I find the 'java' executable?

Comment: Thanks for all the information, however I knew all that already. I know which JRE is being used when I run 'java' in the command line. I know that I am using 'JavaSE-1.6' in Eclipse because it says so. But I don't know which implementation of JavaSE-1.6 that is (e.g. Oracle?), and I don't know how to use that exact implementation to execute smth from command line (where is it on the file system?).

Comment: Obviously, if I install JRE myself and set Eclipse up to use that one,  I can answer the two above questions. But I don't know for the defaultly present JREs, e.g. 'JavaSE-1.6'.

Answer (score 11):

While you are in Eclipse:

- Open Help -> About Eclipse
- click on Installation Details
- select the Tab Configuration

search for the entry

```
eclipse.vm=
```

there should be the path to the used JRE.

Comment: This is the precise and correct answer to the asked question. This should be marked as accepted answer.

Comment: And if Eclipse doesn't start because of wrong Java?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know

- where is **Java located in** your **system**,
  run it in terminal `whereis java`.
- which **Java** is **used in** your **system**, run it in terminal `which java`.
- what **Java version** is **used by default**, run it in terminal `java --version`
- which **JDK** is **used in Eclipse**, refer to `Project->Properties->Java Compiler`
- which **JRE** is **used in Eclipse**, refer to `Windows->Preferences->Installed JREs`

Comment: and the one running Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

It is up to your configuration.

Go to Windows/Preferences, then check:

Java/Installed JREs and Java/Compiler/

You can also override your settings per project: project preferences, Java Compiler.

Comment: In case of multiple installation of JDK?Which one eclipse is using? Question is not about which jvm user project/application is using.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse gives you an option to select the `JDK` on **per project basis** as well as **for All projects.**

**For All projects :**

Windows ---> Preferences ---> Java Compiler ---> Compiler compliance level ---> Select the JDK you wish to work with.

**For Specific projects :**

Project ---> Properties ---> Java Compiler ---> Compiler compliance level ---> Select the JDK you wish to work with.

The settings for the specific project is given priority over the All project settings...

Comment: In case of multiple installation of JDK?Which one eclipse is using? Question is not about which jvm user project/application is using.

Answer (score 1):

*(this is too long for a comment)*

> Let say I want to use that same JRE to execute my Java program from
>   command line, how do I find the 'java' executable?

On Linux the java executable is the first executable named "java" found on your path.

For example:

```
... $  echo $PATH
/home/f/jdk1.6.0_33/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
... $  which java
/home/f/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/java
```

You can install as many JRE/JDK as you want.  You can even trivially create user accounts with Java (*e.g.* a user account for development) and users account without Java (*e.g.* a user account without Java that you'd use only for browsing the Web [see comment]).

If you try to launch Eclipse when the $PATH doesn't contain any Java executable and if you didn't install any JRE/JDK inside *~/eclipse/*, then Eclipse shall complain and refuse to launch:

*"A JRE or JDK must installed in order to launch Eclipse"*

At that point and if you did install Java, you can simply add it to the $PATH and Eclipse shall launch:

```
... $  export PATH=~/jdk1.6.0_33/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Using a separate user account on Linux without Java just to browse the Web is seen as wise by some seen that, since 2011, Java surpassed Flash as the single biggest attack vector for Web-based exploits.  If some site (like some very poorly designed bank websites in the U.S.) mandates the use of Java you can always use a browser from a user account that has Java (I personally think that banking websites should be accessed from Live CDs only but that is another topic ; )

Comment: +1. So user need to change the order of installation path in $PATH variable, in order to use different JDK version which eclipse uses?Any other way?

Comment: Change eclipse.ini to point it to the runtime you want it to specifically use?